# Kitematic Fail after clean setup

Tags: macos, docker, kitematic

I've just install Docker on Mac OS 10.10.5 and ran Kitematic after that and got a hug error right away. This is the beginning of it, I can paste the rest if it will help

> Command failed: /usr/local/bin/docker-machine -D start default,Docker
>   Machine Version: 0.7.0, build a650a40,Found binary path at
>   /usr/local/bin/docker-machine,Launching plugin server for driver
>   virtualbox,Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:62284,()
>   Calling .GetVersion,Using API Version 1,() Calling .SetConfigRaw,()
>   Calling .GetMachineName,command=start machine=default,(default)
>   Calling .GetState,(default) DBG | COMMAND: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage
>   showvminfo default --machinereadable,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default)
>   DBG

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.11.1
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   5604cbe
 Built:        Tue Apr 26 23:44:17 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?


$ docker info
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   -        virtualbox   Stopped                 Unknown
```

Comment: Can you run the following commands from a terminal window and update your question with the results? `docker version` , `docker info` , `docker-machine ls`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read the [Get started with Docker Machine and a local VM](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/) one more time and found I need to run `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"` to setup the env-var for docker on Mac OS X.